# .Net MAUI Android App: Change Navigation and Status Bar colors at Splash screen moment

Tags: android, .net, maui

I'm trying to change Navigation Bar and Status Bar background color in my .Net MAUI Android App.

I found how to do that when the app has initialized an loaded (Status Bar: Using MauiCommunityToolkit StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor feature. Navigation Bar: Using Window.SetNavigationBarColor).

But I have not found how to do that when the app starts and shows the Splash Screen. I need black background color for both, Status and Navigation bar but when the App starts, NavBar is white and Status Bar is Purple (default .Net MAUI color). I attached an image of how it looks when starts.

I tried changing the Primary Color in the Resources/colors.xml, and it didn't work.

My App is a MAUI Single project template (Android and iOS).

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this issue.[image]

UPDATE: I was able to change just Status Bar, changing defautl colorPrimaryDark value in Platforms/Android/Resources/colors.xml
[image]

But still looking at how to change Navigation Bar color.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a new .xml file and then put the style in or add the style to colors.xml directly:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#512BD4</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#2B0B98</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#2B0B98</color>
    
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="@style/Maui.SplashTheme">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In the MainActivity.cs file (Platforms/Android):

```
[Activity(
    //Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme",
    Theme = "@style/SplashTheme",
    MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
```

It works well and can achieve your need.

Comment: Thanks so much @jianwei-sun-msft you rock!! It works as expected, now I can change Navigation Bar Color :)

Comment: @maguilleng You can also see [the source code about styles.xaml](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Core/src/Platform/Android/Resources/values/styles.xml)

Comment: I copy and pasted both your colors.xml and the MainActivity.cs and I am getting an error that the resource style/SplashTheme is not found. Did anyone else have this issue?